# Necessity of docker-machine on Linux

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-engine

According to the [official docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/),

> Docker Machine is a tool that lets you install Docker Engine on virtual hosts, and manage the hosts with docker-machine commands.

Since docker engine can be directly installed on Linux, my question is whether there are any use cases where `docker-machine` is actually needed when working on a Linux environment

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just run small tests on your machine, you should not need it.

It becomes useful when you want to provision other hosts, it may be a virtual machine running on your computer or a remote host.

Why would you want to do this? I can think of 2 cases.

- You can have different virtual hosts with different versions of your system and you can just pause/start them as a whole.
- You may need a bigger machine than your own computer. Even more if you are working on a laptop, it's easy to run out of 16GB (maybe 32?) of ram if you start deploying multiple services.